# SendMessage всем окнам с определенным классом

Tags: c++, winapi

Допустим у меня есть 3 запущенных параллельно окна с одним и тем же классом. При клике в одном из них я хочу отсылать с помощью `SendMessage` информацию остальным, как я могу это сделать? Интересует сам выбор всех окон по этому классу и отправка с помощью `SendMessage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EnumWindows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) + [`GetClassName`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname):

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWndProc(HWND wnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (wnd == (HWND)lParam) return TRUE; //пропускаем своё собственное окно
    TCHAR class_name[256]; // остальные фильтруем по имени класса:
    GetClassName(wnd, class_name, 256);
    if (wcscmp(class_name, MY_CLASS_NAME) == 0) { 
        SendMessage(wnd, WM_MYMESSAGE, WPARAM_VALUE, LPARAM_VALUE);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

...

EnumWindows(EnumWndProc, (LPARAM)my_hwnd);
```